# How to co-simulate fmu with a Python function?

Tags: python, modelica, fmi, pyfmi

With Python libraries like FMPy I am able to simulate fmus (using `fmpy.simulate_fmu`) for given  `start_time` and `stop_time`. In such case, the function simulate_fmu completes the simulation and return the time-series results.

However, I want to create a closed loop between fmu and a Python function (i.e. in a Python script initialize the fmu, get the results from fmu after every 0.1s and based on that update the input value to the fmu for the next timestep). Is there a way to achieve this using existing libraries like fmpy or pyfmi?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is yes the tools you mention are set up to do what you are asking.

A long answer can be found for FMPy:

- [Example from FMPy](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/fmpy/examples/custom_input.py)
- [My own personal variation](https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/ModelicaPy/blob/master/modelicapy/fmpy/runFMUinputs.py)

But the gist is to perform changes during simulation like you are asking the
approach you want you need to go a layer deeper than `simulate_fmu` and use `doStep` and associated setup. The functions/approach needed for these are defined by the FMI standard while highler level implmentations like `simulate_fmu` are not and are therefore tool dependent implementations of the standard.

The cliff notes are:

- Prep the Simulation Inputs

  - e.g., unzip the FMU, define simulation setup, and instantiate the FMU

```
from fmpy import read_model_description, extract
from fmpy.fmi2 import FMU2Slave

# extract the FMU
unzipdir = extract(fmu_filename)

fmu = FMU2Slave(guid=model_description.guid,
                unzipDirectory=unzipdir,
                modelIdentifier=model_description.coSimulation.modelIdentifier,
                instanceName='instance1')

# initialize
fmu.instantiate()
fmu.setupExperiment(startTime=start_time)
fmu.enterInitializationMode()
fmu.exitInitializationMode()
```

- Simulation Loop

  - Set/Get values (can do this before and/or after timestep): `fmu.setReal` and `fmu.getReal`
  - Solve the time step (`fmu.doStep`)
  - Store values
  - Loop until complete
- Terminate Simulation: `fmu.terminate()` and `fmu.freeInstance()`
- Plot results
- Celebrate!

Comment: This worked, I reached to the last bullet point in cliff notes :)